# Converging rays

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

So I need some clarification of Ratcliffe's proof. Condensed information and question below.

[image]

**STATEMENT:** Before I proceed I will give some abbreviate notation. We may assume $c=\infty$. Furthermore, we have two sequences $f_ix_i$ and $f_ig_ix_i$ which converges to $a$ and $b$ ,respectively. If we let $R_i$ be the ray connecting $f_ix_i$ to $f_ig_ix$ then it is claimed that $R_i$ converges to the ray $(a,b)$, but its not clear rigorously why this is true.

**QUESTION:** Why does the sequence of rays $R_i$ converge to the ray $(a,b)$, where convergence is taken with respect to Hausdorff metric.

Comment: The notation of your **STATEMENT** and your **QUESTION** are inconsistent with the passage you have quoted from Ratcliffe: that passage does not even have a $c$. So it is hard to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I am using an older edition of the book. I didn't realize the newer edition pdf has notational changes. I will correct that.

Comment: My guess is that this is a confusion between Hausdorff metric in hyperbolic space using the hyperbolic metric, versus Hausdorff metric in the compactified hyperbolic space using any old compact ball metric. When discussing convergence of rays and lines, usually one uses the compactified hyperbolic space.